Improving the Robustness of Keyword Tagging Function in Python
I have this function:
import pandas as pd

def tag_assemblies_by_levels(df, keywords):
    current_index = 0
    while current_index < len(df):
        # Locate the next instance of the keyword in 'Description'
        keyword_instance = df[current_index:][df['Description'].str.contains(keyword, case=False, na=False)].head(1)
        if not keyword_instance.empty:
            # Get the index of the next instance and the corresponding level
            start_index = keyword_instance.index[0]
            start_level = df.at[start_index, 'Level']
            # Tag the first instance
            df.at[start_index, 'Tag'] = keyword
            
            # Continue tagging rows as long as they are part of the relevant group
            for index, row in df.iloc[start_index + 1:].iterrows():
                current_level = row['Level']
                # Continue tagging if:
                # 1. The level is the same or higher than the start level
                # 2. The keyword is present in the description
                # 3. We haven't reached a new instance of the keyword at the same or higher level
                if (current_level <= start_level or 
                    keyword.lower() in row['Description'].lower() or 
                    (current_level > start_level and df.loc[index:, 'Level'].min() <= start_level)):
                    df.at[index, 'Tag'] = keyword
                else:
                    # Stop tagging if we've reached a new instance
                    break
            
            # Move the current index forward to continue searching for more instances
            current_index = index + 1
        else:
            # If no more instances are found, exit the loop
            break

Which produces an output that looks something like this:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['1', '000100', 'assy, foo, 123'],
     ['2', '000101', 'foo, screw, 123'],
     ['2', '012345', 'nail, 123, 100']
     ['1', '002010', 'assy, bar, 456']
     ['3', '123456', 'bracket, metal, abc']],
    columns=['Level', 'Part Number', 'Description'])

keywords = ['foo', 'bar']

for keyword in keywords:
    tag_assemblies_by_levels(df, keywords)




Level
Part Number
Description
Tag




1
000100
assy, foo, 123
foo


2
000101
screw, foo, 123
foo


2
012345
nail, 123, 100
foo


1
002010
assy, bar, 456
bar


3
123456
bracket, metal, abc
bar



I have pieced this function together from other posts and my own knowledge and it works about 85% of the time. However, there are multiple, repeat instances where the functions bugs when a keyword is found in a higher level, most often when the levels are jumbled around (see below - these should all be labeled as foo):



Level
Part Number
Description
Tag




4
483901
assy, foo, 123
foo


5
851902
screw, 16mm, 123
foo


4
589034
tube, insul, foo
foo


5
089011
seal, alum, 123
NaN


5
123456
bracket, metal, abc
NaN



My goal is to go through an entire BOM,  and scan Description with a list of keywords. Upon finding an instance of the keyword, it notes the level the part is in the  Level column and for every level greater that the original tagged level, it will populate a column called Tag with the keyword - and then go through again with the rest of the keywords.
Given the nature of the bug and the format of my data, I was wondering if there was a way to improve the robustness of the function or just to simply scrap it and start from zero.
